Determinants & Volume
I know that the determinant of a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ whose column vectors are $\mathbf{a}_{1}, \mathbf{a}_{2}, \cdots, \mathbf{a}_{n}$ is equal to the $n$-dimensional volume of the following set(spanned by the column vectors) :
$$ P := \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} t_{i} \mathbf{a}_{i} \; \bigg| \; 0 \le t_{i} \le 1 \right\} $$
But I'm having trouble in this situation : consider a triangular pyramid whose vertices are points $\rm{A}, \rm{B}, \rm{C}, \rm{D}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and denote the volume as $V$. For a linear map $L_{A}$ whose corresponding matrix is $A$, the volume of the triangular pyramid with vertices $L(\rm{A}), L(\rm{B}), L(\rm{C}), L(\rm{D})$ is $\det(A) \cdot V$. Why does this hold? How can I understand this simply and also prove it?
Also, does this hold for any other volume (not only triangular pyramids)?

Yes, it holds for all shapes (for which volume is defined). Convince yourself first that it holds, based on what you've said, when $V$ is the unit cube,

More properly, it should be $|\det A| \cdot V$.
That said, think on a macro level, a very small parallelipiped (say, a cube $[0,\varepsilon]^3$ for a small $\varepsilon > 0$). Then the cube has volume $\varepsilon^3$, and its volume after the transformation is $|\det A| \cdot \varepsilon^3$.
Now envision your solid - doesn't have to be a pyramid, any solid - as being made up of many of these small cuboids; the result will be made up of transformed cuboids. They approximate the respective solids better and better for smaller and smaller $\varepsilon$. The nature of an invertible linear transformation ensures  the images of the original cuboids will not overlap. So you can write the volume of the image as
$$\text{volume of cuboid image} = \sum_{\text{cuboids}} |\det A| \cdot (\text{volume of original cuboid})$$
but this is just the volume of the transformed solid, i.e.
$$\begin{align*}
\text{volume of image} 
&=   \sum_{\text{cuboids}} \text{volume of cuboid images}\\
&= |\det A| \cdot \sum_{\text{cuboids}} (\text{volume of each cuboid}) \\
&= |\det A| \cdot (\text{volume of original solid})
\end{align*}$$
